# Create DOM element with jQuery performance

Tags: jquery, performance, dom, append

Currently I'm using the following code to append certain elements to the DOM:

```
$('<p/>', { html: data } ).appendTo('.columnLeft');
```

But because a lot of elements need to be appended I'm a bit worried about performance. Before I used `{ html: data }` I've tried `{ text: data }`. But because sometimes there's html in the data-variable I've changed it to `{ html: data }`. I don't really have the tools to measure performance, so I was wondering if someone here knows what is faster?

Thanks for reading!

As commented below, I've made my own testcase you can see it [here](http://jsperf.com/appendtestluud). The solution Adam gave is the fastest according to the test.

Comment: You can use http://jsperf.com

Comment: and share the results with us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way to append HTML elements to the DOM using jQuery is to just append them as an HTML string like this:

```
var myHTML = '<p>'+data+'</p>';
$('.columnLeft').append(myHTML);
```

That way jQuery doesn't go through the process of having to create DOM elements before they are actually appended to the DOM.